# wxPython - Display text from two dialogs printed on a third dialog

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am working with three dialog (named: Box1, Box2 and Box3) as seen below:-

Basic calculations are carried out on the Box1 and Box2, how do I display the sum of the calculation the third dialog, that is on Box3?

```
import wx


class Box1 ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,141 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer8 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        bSizer42 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_staticText61 = wx.StaticText( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"item1", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText61.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer42.Add( self.m_staticText61, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_staticText62 = wx.StaticText( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"item2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText62.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer42.Add( self.m_staticText62, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        bSizer8.Add( bSizer42, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        bSizer43 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )


        bSizer43.AddSpacer( ( 80, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        bSizer8.Add( bSizer43, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.item1 = wx.RadioButton( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"7.50", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,20 ), 0 )
        bSizer11.Add( self.item1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.item2 = wx.RadioButton( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"8.00", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer11.Add( self.item2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        bSizer8.Add( bSizer11, 0, 0, 5 )


        self.m_panel2.SetSizer( bSizer8 )
        self.m_panel2.Layout()
        bSizer8.Fit( self.m_panel2 )
        bSizer6.Add( self.m_panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.m_staticText25 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Quatity:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText25.Wrap( -1 )
        self.m_staticText25.SetFont( wx.Font( 15, 70, 90, 92, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        bSizer13.Add( self.m_staticText25, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        quantity_choiceChoices = [ u"1", u"2", u"3", u"4", u"5", u"6", u"7", u"8", u"9", u"10" ]
        self.quantity_choice = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, quantity_choiceChoices, 0 )
        self.quantity_choice.SetSelection( 0 )
        bSizer13.Add( self.quantity_choice, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.ok_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer13.Add( self.ok_button, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.cancel_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Cancel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer13.Add( self.cancel_button, 1, wx.ALL, 5 )


        bSizer6.Add( bSizer13, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer6 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.cancelFunc )
        self.ok_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.okFunc )
        self.cancel_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cancelFunc )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def cancelFunc( self, event ):
        self.Destroy()


    def okFunc(self, event):

        quatity_choice = int(self.quantity_choice.GetStringSelection())

        if self.item1.GetValue():
            price = quatity_choice * 7.5
            print price

        if self.item2.GetValue():
            price = quatity_choice * 8.0
            print price

        Box2(None).ShowModal()






class Box2 ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,141 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer8 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        bSizer42 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_staticText61 = wx.StaticText( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"item3", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText61.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer42.Add( self.m_staticText61, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_staticText62 = wx.StaticText( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"item4", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText62.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer42.Add( self.m_staticText62, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        bSizer8.Add( bSizer42, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        bSizer43 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )


        bSizer43.AddSpacer( ( 80, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        bSizer8.Add( bSizer43, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.item3 = wx.RadioButton( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"1.50", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,20 ), 0 )
        bSizer11.Add( self.item3, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.item4 = wx.RadioButton( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"2.00", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer11.Add( self.item4, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        bSizer8.Add( bSizer11, 0, 0, 5 )


        self.m_panel2.SetSizer( bSizer8 )
        self.m_panel2.Layout()
        bSizer8.Fit( self.m_panel2 )
        bSizer6.Add( self.m_panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.m_staticText25 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Quatity:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText25.Wrap( -1 )
        self.m_staticText25.SetFont( wx.Font( 15, 70, 90, 92, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        bSizer13.Add( self.m_staticText25, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        add_quantity_choiceChoices = [ u"1", u"2", u"3", u"4", u"5", u"6", u"7", u"8", u"9", u"10" ]
        self.add_quantity_choice = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, add_quantity_choiceChoices, 0 )
        self.add_quantity_choice.SetSelection( 0 )
        bSizer13.Add( self.add_quantity_choice, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.ok_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer13.Add( self.ok_button, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.cancel_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Cancel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer13.Add( self.cancel_button, 1, wx.ALL, 5 )


        bSizer6.Add( bSizer13, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer6 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.cancelFunc )
        self.ok_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.okFunc )
        self.cancel_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cancelFunc )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def cancelFunc( self, event ):
        self.Destroy()


    def okFunc( self, event ):

        add_quatity_choice = int(self.add_quantity_choice.GetStringSelection())

        if self.item3.GetValue():
            add_price = add_quatity_choice * 1.5
            print add_price

        if self.item4.GetValue():
            add_price = add_quatity_choice * 2.0
            print add_price


        Box3(None).ShowModal()






class Box3 ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 257,165 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.totalText = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Total is:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.totalText.Wrap( -1 )
        self.totalText.SetFont( wx.Font( 20, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        bSizer13.Add( self.totalText, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.totalText1 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"?", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.totalText1.Wrap( -1 )
        self.totalText1.SetFont( wx.Font( 20, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        self.totalText1.SetLabel(str('price + add_price'))
        # How to I get the "price + add_price" printed above

        bSizer13.Add( self.totalText1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer13 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.cancelFunc )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def cancelFunc( self, event ):
        self.Destroy()





app = wx.App(0)
Box1(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Simple arithmetic is being performed on Box1 and Box2, I want the sum of the results to be displayed on the third dialog (Box3)

How do I get this done?

The code is based on wxpython classic and python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the information collected from each dialog to the next dialog through their **init** methods. Here is a quick working example

```
import wx


class Box1(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=wx.EmptyString, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                           size=wx.Size(500, 141), style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)

        self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        bSizer8 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        bSizer42 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_staticText61 = wx.StaticText(self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"item1", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.m_staticText61.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer42.Add(self.m_staticText61, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.m_staticText62 = wx.StaticText(self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"item2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.m_staticText62.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer42.Add(self.m_staticText62, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer8.Add(bSizer42, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer43 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer43.AddSpacer((80, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer8.Add(bSizer43, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.item1 = wx.RadioButton(self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"7.50", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(-1, 20), 0)
        bSizer11.Add(self.item1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.item2 = wx.RadioButton(self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"8.00", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer11.Add(self.item2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer8.Add(bSizer11, 0, 0, 5)

        self.m_panel2.SetSizer(bSizer8)
        self.m_panel2.Layout()
        bSizer8.Fit(self.m_panel2)
        bSizer6.Add(self.m_panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.m_staticText25 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Quatity:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.m_staticText25.Wrap(-1)
        self.m_staticText25.SetFont(wx.Font(15, 70, 90, 92, False, wx.EmptyString))

        bSizer13.Add(self.m_staticText25, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        quantity_choiceChoices = [u"1", u"2", u"3", u"4", u"5", u"6", u"7", u"8", u"9", u"10"]
        self.quantity_choice = wx.Choice(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, quantity_choiceChoices, 0)
        self.quantity_choice.SetSelection(0)
        bSizer13.Add(self.quantity_choice, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.ok_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer13.Add(self.ok_button, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.cancel_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Cancel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer13.Add(self.cancel_button, 1, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer6.Add(bSizer13, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer6)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.cancelFunc)
        self.ok_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.okFunc)
        self.cancel_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cancelFunc)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def cancelFunc(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def okFunc(self, event):

        quatity_choice = int(self.quantity_choice.GetStringSelection())
        price = 0
        if self.item1.GetValue():
            price = quatity_choice * 7.5
            print price

        if self.item2.GetValue():
            price = quatity_choice * 8.0
            print price

        Box2(None, price).ShowModal()


class Box2(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, price1):
        self.price1 = price1
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=wx.EmptyString, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                           size=wx.Size(500, 141), style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)

        self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        bSizer8 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        bSizer42 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_staticText61 = wx.StaticText(self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"item3", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.m_staticText61.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer42.Add(self.m_staticText61, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.m_staticText62 = wx.StaticText(self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"item4", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.m_staticText62.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer42.Add(self.m_staticText62, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer8.Add(bSizer42, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer43 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer43.AddSpacer((80, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer8.Add(bSizer43, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.item3 = wx.RadioButton(self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"1.50", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(-1, 20), 0)
        bSizer11.Add(self.item3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.item4 = wx.RadioButton(self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"2.00", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer11.Add(self.item4, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer8.Add(bSizer11, 0, 0, 5)

        self.m_panel2.SetSizer(bSizer8)
        self.m_panel2.Layout()
        bSizer8.Fit(self.m_panel2)
        bSizer6.Add(self.m_panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.m_staticText25 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Quatity:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.m_staticText25.Wrap(-1)
        self.m_staticText25.SetFont(wx.Font(15, 70, 90, 92, False, wx.EmptyString))

        bSizer13.Add(self.m_staticText25, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        add_quantity_choiceChoices = [u"1", u"2", u"3", u"4", u"5", u"6", u"7", u"8", u"9", u"10"]
        self.add_quantity_choice = wx.Choice(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                                             add_quantity_choiceChoices, 0)
        self.add_quantity_choice.SetSelection(0)
        bSizer13.Add(self.add_quantity_choice, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.ok_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer13.Add(self.ok_button, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.cancel_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Cancel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer13.Add(self.cancel_button, 1, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer6.Add(bSizer13, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer6)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.cancelFunc)
        self.ok_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.okFunc)
        self.cancel_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cancelFunc)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def cancelFunc(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def okFunc(self, event):

        add_quatity_choice = int(self.add_quantity_choice.GetStringSelection())
        add_price = 0
        if self.item3.GetValue():
            add_price = add_quatity_choice * 1.5
            print add_price

        if self.item4.GetValue():
            add_price = add_quatity_choice * 2.0
            print add_price

        Box3(None, self.price1+add_price).ShowModal()


class Box3(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, total):
        self.total = total
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=wx.EmptyString, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                           size=wx.Size(257, 165), style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)

        self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.totalText = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Total is:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.totalText.Wrap(-1)
        self.totalText.SetFont(wx.Font(20, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString))

        bSizer13.Add(self.totalText, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.totalText1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"?", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.totalText1.Wrap(-1)
        self.totalText1.SetFont(wx.Font(20, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString))

        self.totalText1.SetLabel(str(total))
        # How to I get the "price + add_price" printed above

        bSizer13.Add(self.totalText1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer13)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.cancelFunc)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def cancelFunc(self, event):
        self.Destroy()


app = wx.App(0)
Box1(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```